# Passing route value inside Html.BeginForm but getting zero in the action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I have an action method that receives one parameter:

```
public ActionResult Citizens(string docId){
  //bla bla
}
```

In the view I have the following:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Citizens","DocSearch",FormMethod.Get)){
    @Html.TextBox("docId",null,new {id="txtSearch"})
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

Note that the form method is GET not POST

I have the following Url mapping rule in my RouteConfig class:

```
        routes.MapRoute(name: "DocUrl",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{docid}");
```

When I click the submit button I expect the docId to be the value of the txtSearch. But it's not and instead of subsituting the docid in the route with that value, a query string with the text box value is added to the url. What should I do to get it working?

EDIT: To give more insight let me tell you what I do in my action method. I check for the value of docId, if it's "0" then I just return the View without passing any model. And if it's different from "0", I construct the model and pass it to the View action. And in the razor side, I check if the Model is null. If it's null then I just present a search text box and the submit button, which (according to what I want) goes to the same action method, but this time setting the docId parameter to the value of the search text box. And this should result in constructing the model and send it back to the View, which in return will render the model accordingly.

### VIEW

```
@{if (Model == null)
  {
    <div class="google-search">
        <div>
             @using(Html.BeginForm("Citizens","DocSearch",FormMethod.Get)){
                @Html.TextBox("docId",null,new {id="txtSearch"})
                <input type="submit" value="Search" />
             }   
        </div>
    </div>
  }
  else
  {Render the model}
```

### Action

```
    public ActionResult Citizens(string docId)
    {
        if (docId != "0")
        {
            DocumentCitizenRepository docRepo = new DocumentCitizenRepository();
            IEnumerable<DocumentCitizen> documents = docRepo.Documents.Where(x => x.DocID.Contains(docId)).ToList();
            MiscellaneousRepository miscRepo = new MiscellaneousRepository();
            IEnumerable<DocSearchViewModel> searchResults = (from doc in documents
                                                             join officer in miscRepo.Officers
                                                                  on doc.AddressedOfficerID.Value equals officer.OfficerID
                                                             select new DocSearchViewModel
                                                             {
                                                                 AddressedTo = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", officer.LastName, officer.FirstName, officer.Patronymic),
                                                                 Author = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", doc.LastName, doc.FirstName, doc.Patronymic),
                                                                 DocDate = doc.ReceivedDate,
                                                                 DocNumber = doc.DocID,
                                                                 Content = doc.TextValues.Subject
                                                             }).ToList();
            return View(viewName: "Index", model: searchResults);
        }
        else//We'll check if the model is null on the razor and act accordingly.
        {
            return View(viewName: "Index");
        }

    }
```

This is the HTML I get after submitting:

```
<form action="/DocSearch/Citizens/0" method="get" novalidate="novalidate">
            <input type="text" name="docId" ,id="txtDocNumber"> 
             <input type="submit"  value="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: I suspect that because its a GET method, the value is populated from the route values (the form value which would take precedence in a POST method are probably not even read - why would they be when its not a POST)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I've added more explanation of what I do. Could you please take a look. Maybe my approach is totally wrong.

Comment: Can you post the generated  HTML for the form?

Comment: Generated when, after subitting the form?

Comment: I think you need to take a more traditional approach and have a GET and POST method, where the POST method receives a model containing the search text and then you can redirect to the GET method, passing it the search text if you want to generate a new view (route values take precedence over query string values so I don't think you could make this work)

Comment: In general DocSearch/Citizens/1 and DocSearch/Citizens?docId=1 are hitting the same action and docid is automatically mapped by mvc into docId argument of your action. So I don't really understand your issue. Could you provide an example of URL that is generated when you hit submit?

Comment: My issue is, I get this: DocSearch/Citizens/0?docId=1. So as you can see  0 does not change to 1 but rather, a query string variable is added with the name docId. That's why I get 0 in my action method. This is the most interesting thing to me, as to why the third component of the URL is not substituted with the value passed.

Comment: make docId optional parameter in your route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make docId optional in your route

```
    routes.MapRoute(name: "DocUrl",
                    url: "{controller}/{action}/{docid}",
                    defaults: new {controller = " DocSearch",
                         action = "Citizens",
                         docid = UrlParameter.Optional}

);
```

**Explanation:**

Html.BeginForm implementation uses `UrlHelper.GenerateUrl` which generates Url based on you route collection. Basically it will be the same Url as the one you get by using `@Url.RouteUrl("DocUrl")`